# how to get the script from an qlikview qvw file?

Tags: api, backend, qlikview, getscript

i try to get the script as string from an local qvw file.

i created a simple windows-form-application and add a reference to my local qlikview desktop installation so i can access the object model.

```
                QlikView.Application QVApp;
                QVApp = new QlikView.Application();
                QVApp.OpenDoc(fileName);
```

This code example works very well and the qvw file opens in the local client.

But my goal is to get access to the script.
The [help site from qlik](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2017/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Classes/AppClass/App-class-GetScript-method.htm) tells there is a "getscript" method, but i can't find it.

Any advice on how to find this method or how to access to the script?

thank you very much for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site refers to the Qlik Engine API, something different.

```
ActiveDocument().GetProperties().Script
```

This should work. For a complete API reference, please download API guide here :

https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-2640

Comment: thank you, BrunoMarques.
But there is no option for the getProperties - method from the activedocument-object.
I see in the references that i use an ActiveX component (name Interop.QlikView) from the version 12.0.0.0. Is this a problem?

Comment: QlikView.Application().ActiveDocument().GetProperties() should work!

Comment: Unfortunaly it does not work!
I recorded it (because I can't insert pictures or screenshots here) and upload it here: https://youtu.be/Rba4l0umVMg
so where is my error?

Comment: The version I have on my machine is 12.2, but according to the API Guide this method is available since QlikView 4.x. In your video you are calling GetScript, which doesn't exist, check my example! Following your example, you should have something like QVApp.ActiveDocument().GetProperties().Script.

Comment: unfortunaly there are no accessible getProperties method, see my video at 0:58

Comment: You show that ActiveDocument.GetProperties doesn't exist. Did you try ActiveDocument().GetProperties?

Comment: Bruno, that's it! Thank you very much!